# mongoose `created` date persistence on 'upsert'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose & mongodb. I'm not sure if it's bad googling skills but how do I maintain the `created` date? When I send through the same question, the db creates another copy of the question document with the new times (same for `created` & `updated`) which is obvious here. But ofcourse I only want the `updated` date to change. How is it done?

```
var QuestionSchema = Schema({
    title           : String,
    admin           : {type: String, ref: 'User'},
    created         : {type: Date},
    updated         : {type: Date}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', QuestionSchema);
```

**api.js**

```
           Question.findOneAndUpdate({
                    title       : req.body.question,
                    admin       : req.body.employee,
                    created     : Date(),
                    udpated     : Date()
                },
                req.body,
                {
                    upsert: true
                })
            .exec(function(err, question) {
                console.log(req.body);
            });
```

Comment: You want [`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/). You also need to learn to use the basic ["update operators"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/) as opposed to "overwriting" the whole document, which is what you are presently doing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query is not correct.
You should use below syntax.

query.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, callback)

```
  Question.findOneAndUpdate({
                    title       : req.body.question,
                    admin       : req.body.employee
                            },
                {
                    udpated     : Date()
                },
                req.body,
                {
                    upsert: true
                })
            .exec(function(err, question) {
                   console.log(req.body);
            });
```

Comment: there's a TypeError at .exec(). >>>Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined.